# Mongoose saves with invalid object references

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to use talkative keys in my data model and want to use them to reference in my schema definitions.

```javascript
const LabelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  values: [{
        value: String,
        languageId:{
            type: String,
            ref: 'Language',
            required: true
        }
    }]
})

const LanguageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String
})

const Label    = mongoose.model('Label', LabelSchema)
const Language = mongoose.model('Language', LanguageSchema)
```

But I can save a label without an error with nonexistent language references

```javascript
var data = {
      '_id': 'myLabel',
      values : [{ languageId:'fakeID', value: 'Germany' }]
    }

var label = await Label.create(data)

assert(label._id, data._id)
```

How can I prevent saving by violating referenced object?